# Why do elements end up outside the grid instead of swapping?

Tags: javascript, html, css, swap

There is a grid which has a puzzle where the squares are to be swapped by dragging and dropping in order to recreate an image that is shown next to/below the grid. But when the user drags and drops a square quickly, the grid is disarranged and some of the squares end up outside of the grid. The game still works however and the user can still swap squares in the grid with the ones outside the grid. There is just empty space where the squares outside the grid were meant to be.

I have tried using a different method for dragging and dropping but this bug still occurs despite this, so the problem is not with the method used for dragging and dropping.

How do I fix this?

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c5ayk3re/

```js
let images = [{
    src: "https://picsum.photos/200",
    title: "the first image"
  },
  {
    src: "https://picsum.photos/200",
    title: "the second image"
  },
  {
    src: "https://picsum.photos/200",
    title: "the woffle image"
  },
  {
    src: "https://picsum.photos/200",
    title: "the puzzel image"
  },
  {
    src: "https://picsum.photos/200",
    title: "the lone image"
  },
  {
    src: "https://picsum.photos/200",
    title: "the noone image"
  },
  {
    src: "https://picsum.photos/200",
    title: "the ,mdp image"
  },
  {
    src: "https://picsum.photos/200",
    title: "the dfkg image"
  },
  {
    src: "https://picsum.photos/200",
    title: "the title image"
  },
];
let dragindex = 0;
let steps = 0;
let draged = null;
let sortUl = document.querySelector(".sort");
let sortLi;
let actImg = document.querySelector(".act-img img");
let levels = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".show span"));
let start = document.querySelector(".show button");
// on start game

// handle active function
let handleActive = function(span) {
  span.currentTarget.parentElement
    .querySelectorAll(".active")
    .forEach(ele => {
      ele.classList.remove("active");
    });
  span.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
};
levels.forEach(level => {
  level.addEventListener("click", e => {
    handleActive(e);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("level", e.currentTarget.dataset.mode);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("level1", e.currentTarget.textContent);
  });
});
let unshuffled = [];
let shuffled = [];
let arr = [];
let sizeUi = 400;
let actLevel = document.querySelector(".act-level span");
start.addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector(".show").style.left = "-100%";
  actLevel.textContent = window.sessionStorage.getItem("level1");
  const randomImg = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)].src;
  actImg.src = randomImg;
  let level = window.sessionStorage.getItem("level");
  if (!level) level = 3;
  let size = level * 100;
  let percent = 100 / (level - 1);
  unshuffled = [];
  arr = [];
  for (i = 0; i < level * level; i++) {
    let x = percent * (i % level);
    let y = percent * Math.floor(i / level);
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.style.cssText = "background-image: url(" + randomImg + ");";

    li.setAttribute("data-num", i);
    li.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
    li.setAttribute("id", `id-${i}`);

    li.style.backgroundSize = size + "%";
    li.style.backgroundPosition = x + "%" + y + "%";

    if (window.innerWidth < 315) {
      li.style.width = 225 / level + "px";
      li.style.height = 225 / level + "px";
    } else if (window.innerWidth < 375) {
      li.style.width = 250 / level + "px";
      li.style.height = 250 / level + "px";
    } else if (window.innerWidth < 450) {
      li.style.width = 300 / level + "px";
      li.style.height = 300 / level + "px";
    } else if (window.innerWidth < 550) {
      li.style.width = 350 / level + "px";
      li.style.height = 350 / level + "px";
    } else {
      li.style.width = 400 / level + "px";
      li.style.height = 400 / level + "px";
    }

    unshuffled.push(li);
    arr.push(li);
  }
  for (let i = unshuffled.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    const temp = unshuffled[i];
    unshuffled[i] = unshuffled[j];
    unshuffled[j] = temp;
  }
  unshuffled.forEach(e => {
    sortUl.appendChild(e);
  });
});
// let act_arr = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".sort li"));

/////////////////////////////////////
sortUl.addEventListener("dragstart", dragstart);
sortUl.addEventListener("dragover", dragover);
sortUl.addEventListener("drop", drop);

function dragstart(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", e.target.id);
}

function dragover(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

function drop(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const clone = e.target.cloneNode(true);
  let data = e.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
  if (document.getElementById(data)) {
    if (clone.id !== data) {
      let nodelist = document.querySelector(".sort").childNodes;
      for (let i = 0; i < nodelist.length; i++) {
        if (nodelist[i].id === data) {
          dragindex = i;
        }
      }
      const targetElement = document.getElementById(data);
      if (targetElement) {
        document
          .querySelector(".sort")
          .replaceChild(document.getElementById(data), e.target);
        document
          .querySelector(".sort")
          .insertBefore(
            clone,
            document.querySelector(".sort").childNodes[dragindex],
          );
      }
    }
  }
}
/////////////////////////////////
let count = document.querySelector(".count");

let win = document.querySelector(".body .win");
const playMore = document.querySelector(".win span");
sortUl.addEventListener("dragend", e => {
  const actElements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".sort li"));
  const correctOrder = Array.from(arr).map(piece => piece.id);
  if (actElements.every((piece, index) => piece.id === correctOrder[index])) {
    win.style.left = "15%";
    win.style.transform = "translate(-50%)";
    document.querySelector(".win .count").textContent = steps;
  } else {
    steps++;
    count.textContent = steps;
  }
});
playMore.addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector(".show").style.left = "0";
  win.style.left = "-100%";
  document.querySelectorAll(".sort li").forEach(e => {
    e.remove();
  });
});
document.getElementById("exit").onclick = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll(".sort li").forEach(e => {
    e.remove();
  });
  document.querySelector(".show").style.left = "0";
  steps = 0;
  count.textContent = "0";
};
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@600&family=Oswald&family=PT+Sans+Narrow&family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap");
@font-face {
  font-family: LapsusPro;
  src: url('LapsusPro-Bold.otf');
}

* {
  font-family: LapsusPro, sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.head {
  text-align: center;
}

.head h1 {
  background-color: #2196f3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.head p {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: -6px;
}

.body {
  display: flex;
  gap: 3rem;
  background: #03a9f4;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 1rem;
  }
}

.body .show {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #607d8b;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 2rem;
}

.body .show h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #3333;
  margin: 0;
}

.body .show span {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  background-color: #03a9f4;
  padding: 5px 16px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.3;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.body .show span.active,
.body .show span:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.body .show button {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  background-color: #3f51b5;
  color: #fff;
  font-style: oblique;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}

.game-page {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column
}

.body ul {
  /* flex: 1;  */
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  padding-left: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .body ul {
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  .body ul {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .body ul {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 315px) {
  .body ul {
    width: 225px;
    height: 225px;
  }
}

.body ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* .body ul li:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
} */

.body .act-img {
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
}

.body .act-img img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.body .steps {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 23px;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

.body .steps+div {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.body .act-level {
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.body .act-level button {
  padding: 5px 12px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #607d8b;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

.body .win {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  background-color: #2196f3;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  left: -100%;
  top: 15%;
  transform: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 5;
}

.body .win h2 {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.body .win .steps {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.body .win span {
  display: block;
  background-color: #607d8b;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="head">
    <h1>PUZZLE</h1>
    <p> Drag each piece to match the image below</p>
  </div>
  <div class="body" style="position: relative">
    <div class="show">
      <h2>choose your game mode</h2>
      <span class="active" data-mode="3">easy</span>
      <span data-mode="4">medium</span>
      <span data-mode="5">hard</span>
      <span data-mode="6"> very hard</span>
      <button>start game</button>
    </div>
    <div class="game-page">
      <ul class="sort">
      </ul>
      <div class="option">
        <div class="steps">Moves:</div>
        <div class="count">0</div>
        <div class="act-img">
          <img src="imgs/img-01.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="act-level">
          <span>easy for test</span>
          <button id="exit">exit img</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="win" style="opacity: 1;">
      <h2>congratulation you made it ^_^</h2>
      <div class="steps">you win in:</div>
      <div class="count">0</div>
      <span>Play More</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing an error, is it in a specific mode? Because I just did easy and it worked fine.

Comment: @AJAnde No it isn't it happens when you swap it very quickly so if you pressed on a square, flicked your mouse then dropped it without clearly placing it on another square the bug happens. So you can't play the game quickly

Comment: If they play that quick then send them a message, send them back to menu or reset the game,